# How can I access the summary information of a dll file installed in the GAC directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, setup-project, .net-framework-version, gac

I created a DLL file to be installed in the GAC directory and created automatically an XML file for the summary information of this DLL file. When I try to install the DLL file and XML file to the GAC directory with the VS Setup project, the installation of the XML file to the GAC directory is not allowed.

Is there a way to access summary information about the DLL file I installed in the GAC file? Since user applications will use this DLL file during development, they need to access information about the functions and function entries in the DLL and so on. Some of the user applications are not .NET applications and during runtime, they try to reach the DLL file via the path given during development. In other words, it is not possible to use the local path to reach DLL during development and access it automatically via GAC ​​during runtime.

I try to install the DLL file and XML file to the GAC directory with the VS Setup project, but the installation of the XML file to the GAC directory is not allowed.

Comment: I think putting an XML file in the GAC folder is not a viable solution and you need to find an alternative one. Since there are non-.NET apps besides the .NET apps, you may want to use a *common place* to store the summary info for all apps. Then using the Windows Registry comes to my mind.